# How to customize tcpdf page size?

Tags: laravel, barcode, tcpdf

I am using a library from [github repo](https://github.com/elibyy/tcpdf-laravel) to generate a different report for my project. My problem now is i am required to use a printer which is smaller than what i regular printer, label sticker printer for barcode and QR code in particular. In documentation it says it can be modify by adding this:

```
PDF::changeFormat('A6');
PDF::reset();
```

so my code looks like this:

```
public function generateBarcodeReport(){
        PDF::SetTitle('Barcode Report');
        PDF::changeFormat('A6');
        PDF::reset();
        PDF::AddPage();
        PDF::SetFont('freeserif', 'B', 8);
        PDF::SetMargins(2, 2, 7, true);
        PDF::SetXY(2,2);

        if($this->reference){
            $style = array(
                'border' => false,
                'padding' => 0,
                'fgcolor' => array(0, 128, 62),
                'bgcolor' => false
            );

            PDF::write1DBarcode($this->reference, 'C128', '', '', '', 18, 0.4, $style, 'N');

        }
        PDF::Output($this->reference.'_Barcode.pdf', 'I');
        exit;
}
```

How can i set my page report to fit into something **20mm-80mm** label sticker?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a custom size by passing an orientation and an array of dimensions to the `AddPage()` method.

```php
// PDF::AddPage($orientation,[$width,$height]);

PDF::AddPage('L',[80,20]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Somehow i manage to change the size by passing an array argument into `changeFormat()` method.